# How do you create a new version of an API using serverless framework?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have a simple API developed using serverless framework that is deployed in production. The serverless.yaml is similar to this one:

```
service: example

provider:
    name: aws

plugins:
    - serverless-plugin-scripts
    - serverless-offline

functions:
    package:
        runtime: nodejs14.x
        handler: build/index.handler
        events:
            - httpApi: "POST /test"
```

The API will change in the next version and I want to offer backward compatibility to my clients. I want to create a `/v1/test` route in API Gateway that will point to the new implementation of the function and I want `/test` to remain the same.

Is there a way to do this using serverless framework?

Comment: I think `/v1/test` should be '/v2/test' and `/test` should be '/v1/test'. Now, when you need to offer backward compatibility what kind of changes are we talking about here? If they are just addition, it could be a smooth change, but deletion and updating the URL could be breaking changes. Need more information to provide some input.

Comment: I agree that it should have been `/v1/test` and `/v2/test` but `/test` has already been deployed to production so we can change it to `/v1/test`. The new implementation of `/v2/test` contains a breaking change.

Comment: I think in this case whenever you make any changes, you need to update the client that this update has breaking changes and they need to accommodate those changes so you need to keep the /test until all the clients are updated. This is why we call them backwards incompatible and this will be definitely a major change in the API version.

Comment: I know this. I am asking how to do this using serverless framework.

Comment: You need to add newer version of endpoint in API gareway and let all the clients know that this release includes new API version with breaking  and the /test API will be supported only by next release. I mean the gist is your clients need to accomodate breaking changes in their application by updating their code and you have to communicate these changes using release notes or any kind of documentation your are following.

Comment: Why not use the `Accept-Version` header instead of polluting your URL with a version number? That way, you will have backward compatibility and forward compatibility. The URL remains the same to all your clients. In your code, you check for the `Accept-Version` header. In your case, if the `Accept-Version` header doesn't exist, default it to the original version, if it does exist and equals 2 or 1.1 or whatever you choose, then branch off in your code to another function to handle the new features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you can do.

1. Create a new function entirely, with a new route. This option is simplest to implement, but your setup may not allow you to create a new function for some reason (CloudFormation stack limits, or other non-functional reasons).

```yaml
functions:
    # V0 package function
    package:
        runtime: nodejs14.x
        handler: build/index.handler
        events:
            - httpApi: "POST /test"
    # V1 package function
    packageV1:
        runtime: nodejs14.x
        handler: build/index.handlerv1
        events:
            - httpApi: "POST v1/test"
```

1. Use the same function, but append a new path. Then inside your function code inspect the `event` payload to determine which path was called and use that to modify the response or functionality to adhere to either API spec.

```yaml
    package:
        runtime: nodejs14.x
        handler: build/index.handler # Both routes share the function, you'll need to modify logic to implement both v0/v1 spec
        events:
            - httpApi: "POST /test" # V0 route
            - httpApi: "POST v1/test" # V1 route
```

Both of these are good for temporary migrations where you'll eventually deprecate the old API. If you need both in perpetuity, you could also migrate your v0 API into a new stack (or similarly create a new stack for the v1 API).

Lambda is priced per-invocation, not per-function. So with that in mind, I'd suggest creating a totally distinct function, that will make it easier to deprecate and delete when the time comes.

Comment: What I don't like about these approaches is that I have to handle in the code both v0 and v1 which increases the complexity of the code base without being necessary.

I would love to just mark somehow the old `- httpApi: "POST /test"` as deprecated and add a new one with `- httpApi: "POST /v1/test"`. I want the `/test` route in API Gateway to point to the same old lambda function and I want `/v1/test` route to point to the new AWS Lambda with the new code deployed.

Comment: Then you'd want to go with the first option, or likely the last choice - which is to migrate your deprecated endpoint to a new stack. Within the Serverless Framework there's no way to remove a lambda function without also deleting it from AWS.

Comment: Thanks! Yea. This makes Serverless Framework quite hard to use for API development.

Comment: I don't know of another tool that would let you do this. CDK, SAM, terraform, etc are all designed to derive and store state from the configuration template.